# how to remove first x characters from a string in a list

Tags: python, string, list

So I have a list and a couple of string in it. I just want to remove the first 7 characters from each of the strings. How do I do that?

I've tried:

```
lst = ["1234567something", "1234567smthelse"]

for i in lst:

    i [7:]

print lst
```

But I get the same list from the beginning...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When doing `i [7:]` you are **not actually editing** the element of the list, you are just computing a new string, without the first 7 characters, and not doing anything with it.

You can do this instead :

```
>>> lst = [e[7:] for e in lst]
>>> lst
['something', 'smthelse']
```

This will loop on the elements of your array, and remove the characters from the beginning, as expected.

Comment: right, stupid me, I didn't save the edited data into the list itself... thanks for helping a beginner out :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
lst = ["1234567something", "1234567smthelse"]
newlst=[]
    for i in lst:
        newlst.append(i[7:])

print newlst
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

`i[7:]` is not inplace, it returns a new string which you are doing nothing with.

You can create a new list with the required string:

```
lst = [string[7:] for string in lst]
```

Or you can modify the same list:

```
for idx, string in enumerate(ls):
    ls[idx] = string[7:]
```

Answer (score 3):

You never reassigned the lst in your question, which is why the output of lst in print(lst) does not change. Try reassigning like this:

```
lst = ["1234567something", "1234567smthelse"]
lst = [i[7:] for i in lst]
print(lst)
```

returns

> ['something', 'smthelse']

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for i in range(0, len(lst)):
   lst[i] = lst[i][7:]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not saving the value of `i[7:]` anywhere… Just create a new list with the trimmed values:

```
lst = [i[7:] for i in lst]
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
lst = [s[7:] for s in lst]
```